# Training a DeepAR time series model with monthly data. Can only train on Daily

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, amazon-sagemaker, deepar

I am training a [DeepAR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/deepar.html) model ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04110)) in Jupyter Notebook. I am following [this](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/deepar_synthetic/deepar_synthetic.html) tutorial.

I create a collection of time series (`concat_df`), as needed by the DeepAR method:

[image]

Each row is a time series. This collection is used to train the DeepAR model. The input format expected by DeepAr is a list of series. So I create this from the above data frame:

```
time_series = []
for index, row in concat_df.iterrows():
    time_series.append(row)
```

With this list of time series I then set the `freq`, `prediction_length` and `context_length` (note I am setting frequency to Daily in this first example):

```
freq = "D"
prediction_length = 3
context_length = 3
```

...as well as the `T-Naught`, `Data Length`, `Number of Time Series` and `Period`:

```
t0 = concat_df.columns[0]
data_length = concat_df.shape[1]
num_ts = concat_df.shape[0]
period = 12
```

I create the training set:

```
time_series_training = []
for ts in time_series:
    time_series_training.append(ts[:-prediction_length])
```

..and visualize this with the test set:

```
time_series[0].plot(label="test")
time_series_training[0].plot(label="train", ls=":")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

So far so good, everything seems to agree with the tutorial.

I then use the remaining code to invoke the deployed model as explained in the referenced article:

```
list_of_df = predictor.predict(time_series_training[:5], content_type="application/json")
```

BUT, if I change the frequency to monthly (`freq = "M"`) I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Units 'M', 'Y', and 'y' are no longer supported, as they do not represent unambiguous timedelta values durations.
```

Why would monthly data not be accepted? How can I train monthly data on DeepAR? Is there a way to specify some daily equivalent to monthly data?

This appears to be some kind of Pandas error, as shown [here](https://fixexception.com/pandas/units-m-y-and-y-are-no-longer-supported-as-they-do-not-represent-unambiguous-timedelta-values-durations/).

Comment: you need 300 observations minimum for DeepAR, so your data would have to go back to 1997, which it does not appear to

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan but that wouldn’t explain the error would it?